# isInstance() on same class returns false during exception handling

Tags: java, exception, isinstance

I am new to java and was trying to implement the isInstance() in a particular exception handling scenario.

```
try {

       ....
       ..//some condition
          throws MyException(); //  --> MyException extends RuntimeException

}catch(Exception e){
       if(e.getClass().isInstance(MyException.class))  // --> This returns false
                .. //do something
}
```

The above isInstance() returns false.
When I debug, **e.getClass() has a value** :

> in.soumav.exceptions.MyException (id=133)

and **MyException.class has value:**

> in.soumav.exceptions.MyException (id=133)

Which concept am I missing at?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't catch the specific Exceptions? Code-reuse? In that case check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211286/is-it-possible-in-java-to-catch-two-exceptions-in-the-same-catch-block

Comment: `instanceof` is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it backwards.

It should be:

```
if (MyException.class.isInstance(e))
```

The Javadoc:

> **boolean java.lang.Class.isInstance(Object obj)**
>
> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class.

So, if you want to check if the exception instance reference by `e` is assignment compatible with the class `MyException`, you should pass `e` as an argument to `MyException.class.isInstance()`.

As an alternative, you can use `isAssignableFrom`:

```
if (e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(MyException.class))
```

Comment: `e instanceof MyException` would be better

Answer (score 2):

MyException.class is an instance of Class and not of MyException, so

```
MyException.class.isInstance(e)
```

should do it, but your purpose should be handled like:

```
try {

      ....
      ..//some condition
         throws MyException(); //  --> MyException extends RuntimeException

}catch(MyException e){
    ... //do something
}catch(Exception e){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ups, i'm late, but i still think it should be handled with a catch block